# How to use previous slot value in Alexa Skill?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, alexa-skills-kit

I want to build the closed dialog model in Alexa skill. The example requirement is

```
Man: Alexa, what is the price of product1

Alexa: The price of product1 is 89 USD

Man: What is the size of it?
```

If I ask the size intent with "it" instead of product name, how alexa will understand the meaning of "it" is the product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the scope of a single session, you can persist the product name as a session attribute, and retrieve it again when responding to the size question.

When handling the price intent, you'll want to save off the name of your product as a [session attribute](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interface-reference#session-object). Lets call that attribute 'ProductName'. Then when handling the size intent within the same session, simply check if the ProductName attribute has been defined, and prompt for it if not.

---

To make this conversation more robust, define the following sample utterances in your second intent (lets call it SizeIntent) to allow a ProductName [custom slot](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interaction-model-reference#custom-slot-syntax):

```
SizeIntent What is the size of it
SizeIntent What is the size of {ProductName}
```

This defines a ProductName slot, so now you have two possible methods of input:

- ProductName Session Attribute, via a previous part of the conversation.
- ProductName Slot Value, via the most recent request.

To decide which value to reference:

- If ProductName slot is not null, save it to your 'ProductName' session attribute and use it.
- Else if ProductName attribute is not null, use it.
- Else, prompt for ProductName.